# How to do standardization on time series data with Scikit-learn Standard Scaler?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, keras, time-series, data-processing

I am using [Keras](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/), so the shape of data is (batch_size, timesteps, input_dim). And [Standard Scaler](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html) just fits 2D data.

One solution I thought was using partial fit and then transform.

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
for sample in range(data.shape[0]):
    scaler.partial_fit(data[sample])

for sample in range(data.shape[0]):
    data[sample] = scaler.transform(data[sample])
```

Is this a correct/efficient approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two possibilities

```
data = np.random.randn(batch_size*time_length*nb_feats).reshape((bsize,time,feats))
```

Version 1 is doing what you say:

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
for sample in range(data.shape[0]):
    scaler.partial_fit(data[sample])

for sample in range(data.shape[0]):
    data[sample] = scaler.transform(data[sample])
```

Another possibility (Version 2) is to flatten the array, fit and transform and then reshape it

```
scaler = StandardScaler()
data   = scaler.fit_transform(data.reshape((bsize*time,feats))).reshape((bsize,time,feats))
```

In my computer

Version 1 takes 0.8759770393371582  seconds

Version 2 takes 0.11733722686767578 seconds

Comment: Should version 1 be chosen when the data is too big?

Comment: yeah, you can use partial_fit if the data is too big. However you dont need to iterate through samples one by one. This takes too much time. Maybe you can do partial fits on batches