# Can I use MinMaxScaler on multivariate data with different shapes?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have some data, a dataset of shape (10000, 18), 18 features, 10000 rows. It's time series data so I'm splitting it 80/20, train/test.

I'm then copying my train dataset, and removing the column I want to predict, and removing all other columns from my y set.

So I get train_x, train_y of shapes (80000, 17) and (80000, 1), i.e. those 17 features to predict the 1.

I do the same for the test set and get the same shapes.

I'm using `MinMaxScaler` `fit_transform` on the training set (all 18 features) before it is split into x & y, and I'm using fit() on the test set.

I can train my model - it seems to be going ok, and I can get predictions from my test_X (pass in my (20000, 17) and get (20000, 1) out, so it seems to be working...)

My problem comes when I want to inverse the scaling, I'm getting:

```
ValueError: non-broadcastable output operand with shape (20000,1) doesn't match the broadcast shape (20000,18)
```

It makes sense, I know logically why this is happening, I'm just not sure how to fix it - should I create a new scaler and use it only on the (20000, 1) set? Wouldn't then mean that the scale for the prediction and the data I'm feeding in is different?

What's the best way to fix this?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you trained a scaler on your _input features_, and then you're trying to use it to inverse scale your _output_ is that correct? Because that's like seting a color dropper to match the color of your oranges and then trying to compare it to the color of your apples. If you want to train a sclaer to scale your targets and inverse scale your predictions, that should be a separate scaler object than the one you use for one or more inputs.

Comment: BTW, general questions about theory and best practices like this might be a better fit for [datascience.se]

Comment: Sorry, I'm getting myself all tied in knots with this one - it seemed like a programming question on the face of it.

Unfortunately, using two scalers is proving more complicated that I first thought. When I am splitting my sets into input / output, I was converting to an numpy.ndarray, which I can't seem to convert back to a DataFrame in order to scale it.

Comment: Also, some clarification from your first post - I trained my scaler on all input, all 18 features, then split them into 17 / 1 - but I cant inverse because (x, 1) doesn't match (x, 18)

Comment: Separating your input features from your targets should be step 1. If you include your targets in the steps you take on your features, you run the risk of introducing data leakage between your training and testing sets. My usual workflow: Train/Test Split (or in your case perhaps timeseriessplit?)->`fit_transform` scalers, imputers, encoders on training features->`fit_transform` scalers, encoders on training targets->Use fitted feature transformers on testing features->Use fitted target transformers on testing targets->train model->predict with model->evaluate performance

Comment: Thanks for your help G.

I think looking at it, I do have a contamination problem... As you indicate, I first split my dataset into test/train, I then split both sets into input and output, so 17 features in, 1 feature out.

Unfortunately ,I then used a MinMaxScaler to scale the 17 features in, on both sets, which is where my contamination is coming in. I'm still researching to see if I can find a way to do this correctly. I can't use two, one for training and one for testing because they input and output are different shapes, but if I use one for input and one for output I'm contaminating

Comment: I don;t know if this will help or not, time series gets complicated quickly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53075203/how-to-do-standardization-on-time-series-data-with-scikit-learn-standard-scaler